# Migrate from Oracle RDBMS to AWS S3 with Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Any suggested architecture ?

1. For the first full load, using Kinesis, how do I automate it so that it creates different streams for different tables. (Is this the way to do it?)
2. Incase if there is a new additional table, how do I create a new stream automatically.
   3.How do I load to Kinesis incrementally (whenever the data is populated )

Any resources/ architectures will be definitely helpful. Using Kinesis because multiple other down stream consumers might access this data in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend looking into AWS Schema Conversion Tool (AWS SCT) and AWS Database Migration Service (AWS DMS). DMS does not necessarily use Kinesis but it is specifically design for this use case.

Start with the walk through in this blog post: ["How to Migrate Your Oracle Data Warehouse to Amazon Redshift Using AWS SCT and AWS DMS"](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-migrate-your-oracle-data-warehouse-to-amazon-redshift-using-aws-sct-and-aws-dms/)